# How could convert the resource to the other type in the xaml file?

Tags: wpf, resources, converters

My English skill is poor because I'm not a native English speaker.
I hope you to understand.

I would like to convert a string resource to the ImageSource.

For example, the string type resource is defined in the Linkes.xaml as shown below.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf.UI.Basic.DarkTheme"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <system:String x:Key="CloseImagePath">/Wpf.UI.Basic;component/Resources/Close.png</system:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And I used the above resource at the Window.xaml(custom control) as shown below.

```
<Image x:Name="CloseImage"
       Source="{DynamicResource CloseImagePath}"
       Stretch="None"
       Margin="4"/>
```

But when I attempted like the above, I faced an error that string type can't convert to the ImageSource type.

So I tried to add a converter that converts from string to ImageSource but I can't it because of can't add the converter to the Resource.

So I want to add the converter to the DynamicResource to convert from the string type to the ImageSource type.

What should I do to achieve the above goal?
I would like to receive your advice.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Instead of a string, you could declare the resource as BitmapImage:. `<BitmapImage  x:Key="CloseImage" UriSource="/Wpf.UI.Basic;component/Resources/Close.png"/>`

Comment: Oh, Thank you to you I solved this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a BitmapImage resource instead of a string:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="CloseImage" UriSource="/Wpf.UI.Basic;component/Resources/Close.png"/>

...

<Image Source="{DynamicResource CloseImage}" .../>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I solved this problem by following your advice.